# How can I insert data in two different models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm newbie in coding, and I'm trying my first Django app.

This time I have three different models, but with a single `form` at the momment when I hit `Save` I want to save data on that form model and in the others 2 models.

So in my display I want to loop the other two models to show what I have.

Is that even possible?

models.py

```
class Personame(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Personlastname(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.last_name


class Personinfo(models.Model):
    personame = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    personlastname = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    hobbies =models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.personame
```

forms.py:

```
class personform(forms.ModelForm):
    personame = forms.CharField(label = "Name")
    personlastname = forms.CharField(label = "Last Name")
    class Meta:
        model = Personinfo
        fields = ["personame","personlastname","address","phone_number","hobbies"]
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    queryset = Personame.objects.all()
    queryset2 = Personlastname.objects.all()
    qs = chain(queryset,queryset2)
    form = personform(request.POST or None)
    context = {
    "qs": qs,
    "form":form,
    }
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save()
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

index.html:

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Save!" />
</form>

            <table >
             <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>

            </tr>
            {% for item in qs  %}
            <tr> 
                <td>{{ item.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.last_name }}</td> 
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </table>
```

Basically I want to save `name` in `Personinfo` and `Personame`, and I want to save `last_name` in `Personinfo` and `Personlastname`. So I can show `Personame` and `Personlastname` in template.

Can anyone help me please?

I would be very happy for your help... **Thanks**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your models don't make any sense at all. They really should be one model. you have not defined any relationship between any of the models. To do that you will have to add a OneToOneField or a ForeignKey. That effectively means you are having an extra column for each item of data. Totally redundant.

```
class Personinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    address = models.TextField()
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    hobbies =models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.personame
```

This makes your life so much easier with simpler coding.

Comment: I need 3 diferent models, one for the form and the others to show in templates. That's why I want to insert in multiple tables from a single form.

Answer (score 0):

your models don't have class Meta , need to define the table name in class meta like :

```
class Meta: 
   managed = True
   db_table = 'tableName'
```

Then u need to override save function in **personform**